# UsageMemory threashold in JConsole

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, jconsole

I am looking into how to use `JConsole` to detect memory leaks.
I see that in `Memory Pool` in my `MBeans` I can define `UsageThreashold` for my `Tenured Generation`.
So if my application exceeds this threashold the heap memory becomes red in the Memory tab.

**Question:** How does this help? I mean how am I supposed to use this setting to analyze my memory? How am I supposed to figure out this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion I don't think that `UsageThreashold` parameter is the most helpful for you to detect memory leaks (but if someone knows some tricks with it, please do share). In my experience that parameter is more helpful to visually understand if my application is getting way too near my max heap size and I'm in danger of getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Still regarding using `JConsole` to search for memory leaks, I don't think there's a silver bullet for the process. But what I usually do is the following:

If exists a memory leak, it means that the objects (the ones that are leaking) won't get collected, hence, your `Tenured Generation` won't fully recover after any amount of GCs.

With the application running I connect `JConsole` and try to spot a leak by observing the memory tab, if after several computations of my application and also after various GCs occurring (including pressing the `Perform GC` button, which will result in a **full gc**) the memory never goes below, or at least to the memory value, it started tracking there's a great possibility that something is leaking. When the leak is big, you can even see a "stair graph" pattern in your memory.

Keep in mind that if your application has long computations running, which may consume memory this analyzes must be done carefully. You must understand when those processes have finished. For example, just run one of those computations and track the total evolution of memory, before, during and afterwards.

Also, I suggest you to try [visualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) instead, because it also allows you to create heap dumps, which you can use in order to understand which objects are still in memory and explore the references graph to understand why they are not being collected.

Comment: But we can see if the application is near the max heap size from the `Overview` or `Memory` tab anyway.

Comment: @Cratylus: yes that's quite true, but if jconsole is running on some other monitor where you are not focusing your attention, a color change that you can easily spot from the corner of the eye is helpful.

Comment: Although I am not 100% sure that there is no other usage I will accept this answer as nothing else came up

Answer (score 0):

you can use JMAP to see the histogram and/or to create heap dumps and study your memory consumption with tools like Eclipse MAT or YourKit.
JConsole is used more for monitoring and running MBeans and less for analysis and in my expirence JVisualvm is better for that since you can use it for sampling your code and see what methods are CPU consuming.